# Ember-data resets queryParam to default value

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my model, I have a queryParam status which is set to refreshModel true in my route.

```
queryParams: {
    status: {
        refreshModel: true
    }
}
```

In my controller, this param is set to 'opened' by default :

```
App.ConversationsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    queryParams: ['status']
    status: 'opened'
});
```

Everytime I set this param to something else, for example 'all', Ember-data resets it to 'opened' and makes two calls instead of one to my model hook, and this behavior has been observed with breakpoints on my model hook (I don't know where it resets), one with param:opened and one with param:all. I even put an observer on it and it effectively does that.

Note that I already searched my code and there is litteraly nowhere where I set this param back to original value.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare them also in your controller to be an expected param in your route

```
App.ConversationsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    queryParams: ['status'],
    status: 'opened'
});
```

Ember has sticky params, as in the docs said.

> By default, query param values in Ember are "sticky", in that if you
>   make changes to a query param and then leave and re-enter the route,
>   the new value of that query param will be preserved (rather than reset
>   to its default). This is a particularly handy default for preserving
>   sort/filter parameters as you navigate back and forth between routes

You can check out more here ... [ember query params](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/query-params/)

You can try to reset them in your route

```
resetController: function (controller, isExiting, transition) {
        if (isExiting) {
          //reset controller to avoid sticky params
          controller.set('status', DEFAULT_VALUE);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Ok, this is so weird. I got two git branches up to date with one another. And they REALLY are up to date. On develop branch, this error happens, queryParams status somewhere changes back to default value before triggering model hook. On conversation branch, this problem doesn't exist, the param keeps the wanted value. I repeat, this is the same code! Do you have any idea what could be going on? (I even copied-pasted the whole code that works into  the other branch, error happens).

Comment: I would need to see an example, maybe in js bin... it can be that is conflicting with a reserved word from ember... but I'm just guessing

Comment: I can't get a good jsBin to work I am so sorry! Maybe you know the answer to my related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749330/how-do-you-retrieve-where-a-property-queryparams-changes-with-ember Oh and by the way, I already had my queryParams declared I just forgot to include it in my example I will edit.

Comment: I found the problem! I had two versions of ember-data in my application without knowing it. On develop branch, I didn't run bundle install after adding ember-rails and ember-source.